# Android how to remove specific data in html String?

Tags: android, html, dynamic-data

In my app i am using url getting html string in that string.I want to `remove` any   `div`with`id ="xyz"`if it exists. How can i do it?

`edit`:here my Html string is `dynamic data.`

Can any one please give some hints/suggestions on how this can be done. Very thankful if you stopby and put some of your thoughts.

Comment: Do you want to remove an entire `div` block that has specific `id` attribute?

Comment: Your question is worded very poorly, and it's hard to understand what you're asking. I appreciate English mightn't be your first language, but please try to rewrite your question so we might be able to better assist you. Thanks!

Comment: @iTech yes remove entair div in specific id attribute

Comment: Have you tried to use `regex`? at least to find the start of the `div` tag with that specific `id`

Comment: how to use `regex` little bit code iam new to html@iTech

Comment: if(strng.contains("your string") then string.replaceall("your string","");

Comment: @ankitmakwana i want remove `entair div data` in specific `id`.

Comment: yes here its remove match string with replcell ""

Answer (score 1):

Let `response` is of **String** type and it contains whole **HTML** response.

```
if (response.contains("<div") == true)
{
   String resp = response.subString(response.indexOf("<div"), response.indexOf("</div>"));
   if (resp.contains("id=\"xyz\"") == true)
       response.replace(resp, "");
}
```

This is just a demo code to give you an idea that how can you achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
String htmltext="<html>body</html>"+

   "<div id ='xyz'>hello Venkat</div>" +
   "<div id ='zyx'>hello my friend</div>";
System.out.println(htmltext.indexOf("<div id ='xyz'>"));
String starttext=htmltext.substring(0, htmltext.indexOf("<div id ='xyz'>"));
System.out.println(htmltext.indexOf("</div>", htmltext.indexOf("<div id ='xyz'>")));
String finalstring=starttext.concat((String) htmltext.subSequence(htmltext.indexOf("  </div>", htmltext.indexOf("<div id ='xyz'>")+3), htmltext.length()));
System.out.println("final string is."+finalstring);
```

> set this code in a method and call this until the  tag is removed